# How to make dual boot where Linux centOS is already installed and I want to install windows 8 into my server

Tags: linux, windows-server-2012

There is a server already running centOS.
I wanted to make it dual boot and i tried but after installing windows when I booted up then Its only windows 8 and I am not finding the dual boot option.

Please help

Answer (score 0):

Install [EasyBCD](http://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/).  Use it to find the install of CentOS on your server, and build a boot menu with the option to access either one.

Comment: Dosen't windows 8 use a different bootloader? (Well, least it looks different).

Comment: I installed Windows 8 onto a dual boot XP/Linux system.  Windows 8 detected that I had Windows XP, and it created it's nice neat boot menu, that ONLY gave me the options of booting to Windows 8 or a "previous version of Windows".  So... I booted to that previous version of Windows, installed EasyBCD, and had it create a boot menu that gave me the choice to boot to all three.